# Why branch out and merge happen in Gitlab though fast forward is set

Tags: gitlab, fast-forward

This is the situation, how is it possible? I hoped fast forward will prevent, and force to do rebase and have a linear branching.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A fast forward merge is not possible in any case.

In fact, it is only possible if the branch that should be merged to contains no commit that are in the branch you merged from.

You may want to do a rebase merge instead.

Also, the gitlab setting does not change the behaviour of the clients. They can do a normal merge if they want to.